# How to use $and inside $match $expr so that it satisfy all the expression in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have been trying since last two days to find all post that satisfy all the criteria for current date, but still haven't figured out the right way

```
const today = await Posts.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $and: [
                        { chk_featured: true },
                        { featured_type: 't' },
                        { $eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: '$publish_date' }, { $dayOfMonth: new Date() }] },

                    ],
                },
            }
        }
    ]);

    if (!today) return res.status(404).json({ msg: "no records found" });
    return res.status(200).json({ today: today });
```

{
"_id": "5f8047b5f5af011b642b6bb1",
"sel_interest_group": ["name2,name1"],
"status": "a",

```
        "title": "aweasdasd",
            "description": "sadsadsa",

                "chk_featured": true,
                    "sel_age_group": "2",

                        "publish_date": {
    "$date": "2020-09-28T18:30:00.000Z"
},

"slug": "aweasdasd",
    "__v": 0,

        "featured_type": "n"
```

},
{
"_id": "5f8047b5f5af011b642b6bb1",

```
"sel_interest_group": ["name2,name1"],
    "status": "a",

        "title": "aweasdasd",
            "description": "sadsadsa",

                "chk_featured": true,
                    "sel_age_group": "2",

                        "publish_date": "2020-10-28T18:30:00.000Z",

                            "slug": "aweasdasd",
                                "__v": 0,

                                    "featured_type": "n"
```

},
{
"_id": "5f8047b5f5af011b642b6bb1",

```
"sel_interest_group": ["name2,name1"],
    "status": "a",

        "title": "aweasdasd",
            "description": "sadsadsa",

                "chk_featured": true,
                    "sel_age_group": "2",

                        "publish_date": "2020-10-23T18:30:00.000Z",

                            "slug": "aweasdasd",
                                "__v": 0,

                                    "featured_type": "t"
```

},
{
"_id":   "5f8047b5f5af011b642b6bb1",

```
"sel_interest_group": ["name2,name1"],
    "status": "a",

        "title": "4th post",
            "description": "sadsadsa",

                "chk_featured": true,


                    "publish_date": "2020-09-28T18:30:00.000Z"


"slug": "aweasdasd",
    "__v": 0,

        "featured_type": "n"
```

}

Unable to figure it out what is wrong in this ,as I am a first time user in Mongodb

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @santimirandarp , no  particular reason - just trying to make it work- find did not work as well it gives "unknown top level operator: $eq"

Comment: here publish_date is matching but other two conditions are not matching

Comment: I believe if you improve a bit the post it will be easier. Include a sample data so I can test the code locally. It would be enough with one or two documents.

Comment: date functionality is matching - but there are similar requirement to match monthly and weekly post - all the comparison are working but I need post which match the date as well as featured_type='t' and chk_featured:true -hence all the documents are being fetched where it is featured true/false and featured_type is of any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, this line from the docs

> `{ $and: [ <expression1>, <expression2>, ... ] }`

implies that you can't have a plain object inside, like this:

```
 { chk_featured: true }
```

but only expressions.

So I tweaked it this way:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
$match: { $expr: {$and: [     
{ $eq:["$chk_featured", true] },
{ $eq:["$featured_type", 't'] },     
{ $eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: '$publish_date' }, { $dayOfMonth: new Date() }] }      
  ]}}
}]);
```

---

**Edit**

This other expression could be easier to read. (Didn't test).

```
db.test.find({ 
 "chk_featured":true, 
 "featured_type":"t", 
 {"$expr": { $eq: [
  { $dayOfMonth: '$publish_date' }, 
  { $dayOfMonth: new Date() }
] } }
})
```